# wiring together polymer components and angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I've just started to experiment with **polymer** and try to use it together with *AngularJS* in one single-page app. Therefore I picked up two `polymer-ui-components`: `polymer-ui-sidebar-menu` and `polymer-ui-pages`. Every time the user selects an item from the sidebar, the pages component should show its item with same index...

*But how to wire these two components?*

I've tried to use the `onclick` event from the menu, but this don't work as expected.

*Maybe there exists any useful documents about **polymer** in the world wide web besides their own documentation?*

**UPDATE:**

*HTML:*

```
<polymer-ui-sidebar-menu label=Channels>
  <polymer-ui-menu-item ng-repeat="channel in channels"
    ng-click=select($index)
    label="{{ channel }}"
    icon=menu>
  </polymer-ui-menu-item>
</polymer-ui-sidebar-menu>
<polymer-ui-pages>
  <span ng-repeat="channel in channels">content: {{ channel }}</span>
</polymer-ui-pages>
```

*Controller:*

```
$scope.select = function (index) {
  angular.element("polymer-ui-sidebar-menu")[0].selected = idx;
  angular.element("polymer-ui-pages")[0].selected = idx;
};
```

*To get the selector in `angular.element(selector)` working, you have to include `jquery` before `angular` and `polymer` before `jquery`!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a video demonstrating how a web component (Polymer element) can talk to an Angular directive: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1NpZ-0Op0w&list=PLRAVCSU_HVYu-zlRaqArF8Ytwz1jlMOIM&index=1

The example in that video data-binds the components' attributes using Angular's data binding feature, but you should be able to use other features to get things working. Have you tried adding `ng-click` on `<polymer-ui-sidebar-menu>`?

Comment: I've found your video a few minutes after my post and I've tried to use your examples for my app, because actually I need `tabs`... *Bad news*: I opened the link showed in the video and saw nothing! *Good news*: I found your corresponding github repository and since then I tried to get thing working... But until now. with no luck. Actually I use the commented polymer version of `tabs.html` because it seems to be your preferred way? At the moment I see my `tabs heading` and a white box below, but no tabs. Also I wrote an issue at github. It would be great, if you can help me! Regards

Comment: Updated the code with recent API changes. Things should work again. The first (commented) `<polymer-element>` uses insertion points and is probably the best way to do tabs. The second way (uncommented) is more similar to the Angular version, which is why it is highlighted in the video.